# @Prompt ([YesNo] does not return expected value

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I am new in this forum, Thank you for your welcome.

I am developping a db.

I am using @Prompt ([YesNo] formula but when I get the rep, it is empty.

```
rep = @Prompt ([YesNo];"C.C.F - Consolidation des repas";"Etes-vous sûr de continuer ?");
@Prompt ([Ok];""; @Text(rep));
@If (rep=1;@Command([ToolsRunMacro];"Consolidation Repas Cantine");@Nothing)
```

Why is that so ? I should receive 1 or 0.

Regards.

Comment: The = is always a comparison operator in Formula language.

Answer (score 3):

You have to assign a value to a variable with `:=`.

Change your code to

```
rep := @Prompt ([YesNo]...
```